# wp_list_categories() with attachment post types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm working on a pictures gallery, where there is no 'regular' post, only images with several custom taxonomies, some of them being hierarchical.

I use `wp_list_categories()` to display hierarchical lists of terms and that works fine provided I set the `hide_empty` parameter to `0`.
However, I would like to display only terms that have pictures, or whose descendants have pictures. But I can't find a way to use `hierarchical` instead of `hide_empty`, probably because the function looks for terms attached to regular posts.

Is there a way to change its behaviour and make it look for `post-type='attachment'` or whatever, so I could list only terms related to published pictures?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register your taxonomy, set the `update_count_callback` argument to `_update_generic_term_count`. This will count all objects associated to taxonomy terms so you don't need to use `hide_empty`.

```
$args = array(
    // your other taxonomy arguments here
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_generic_term_count'
);
register_taxonomy( 'your-taxonomy', array( 'attachment' ), $args );
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work with the `wp_list_categories()` function too? Because I can't see any difference with the `_update_generic_term_count` parameter.

It's either `hide_empty` set to `false` and I get everything; or `hide_empty` is `true` and the only children categories I get are those containing media attached to some post (the home page in fact, as it is the only one that uses attached media).

And by the way, the `pad_counts` parameter doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you just changed that parameter then term counts are still wrong since you've associated the attachments before making that change. You either need to manually update the term count field or re-add terms to attachments to fix the count.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have done it, though I'm a bit surprised I had only to remove/add each term from one media only to get the counter right.